# Magento 2 collection filter need advies

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, collection, product-collection

We have grouped products - rims. Now we want to sell it with tires.

Logical is to look up for needed tires and show them, although the problem is if we do that we get results for front and back. but we can get full page of tires that are only for front or for rear rim.

is there a way to rearrange this collection so it will show front, rear based on manufacturer for example.